# Where can I find calendar from Primefaces documentation?

Tags: primefaces

On 286 page (`Layout` component) of Primefaces [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf) there is great calendar. Where can I find it? Or what components could be used to create it.

Comment: Next time please read the documentation a little more, check the the 'content' section and try the showcase. These kinds of questions do not belong in stackoverflow in my opinion and show very little effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the primefaces [schedule](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml).